# How do I obtain manage_pages permission for my application from facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have an application, that is registered in facebook, and I want to ask the users for `manage_pages` permission. I failed to do obtain the token both with the `PHP facebook SDK`

```
$loginUrl = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($myLoginUrl)->getLoginUrl(['manage_pages']);
```

And using just plain HTTP:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=manage_pages,user_tagged_places&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URI`

The first signal that something is wrong is that the facebook popup asks 
only for `public_profile`, second signal is that once I obtain the `access_token` token and run it through `https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=OBTAINED_TOKEN`
it only displays `public_profile`

Do I need to change the settings of my Facebook application to ask users for `manage_pages`?

Comment: That first line is not valid PHP code. What account are you using to test this? If you use an account without a role in the app, then of course you need to get the permission reviewed first.

Comment: I can obtain other kinds of permissions, but I fail to obtain just the `manage_pages`

Comment: I am testing it with multiple accounts

Comment: That‘s probably because your login dialog URL doesn‘t contain an API version - so it will fall back to the lowest one your app can use. And in that, the permission might not have existed already (although then as the app admin you should see a warning message in that regard in the login dialog.) So how did you initialize the SDK …?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the application is **not yet reviewed by facebook** and the accounts I was testing it **do not have any role** in the app.

Relevant documentation part: [more here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-manage_pages)

`If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to review how your app uses it. You can grant this permission on behalf of people listed within the Roles section of your App's Dashboard without review by Facebook.`